# Azure DF cannot re-run an Azure ML pipeline:

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

I am struggling to re-run an Azure Machine Learning (ML) pipeline, via an Azure Data Factory (DF) pipeline.

This is the error:
**Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (User starting the run is not an owner or assigned user to the Compute Instance).
User starting the run is not an owner or assigned user to the Compute Instance**

what I have already tried:

1. ensure the compute instance is up and running in Azure ML
2. created a linked service in Azure DF using the Azure DF managed identity
3. granted the Azure DF managed identity a role assignment in Azure ML - contributor

Comment: I have now even granted the Azure DF managed identity the Owner role assigned in Azure ML and the error is still occuring

Answer (score 0):

Aha

I found a solution.

Instead of using a Compute Instance, a Compute Cluster seems to do the job.

And in theory should be the same costing as I set the maximum node count to 1 using the same pricing tier (RAM and CPU combo).